# Creating a specific cream for a cake?

Tags: dessert, frosting, filling

My grandma used to make a waffle cake with chocolate cream filling, Romanian/Hungarian/Russian style.

My mom is trying to recreate it, without success. But she doesn't exactly know how to make the cream.

I had one recipe with sweet cream and chocolate pudding, but it didn't work well — it was too wet.

I had another recipe with cocoa and halva, where you cook them both with some water, butter and sugar, and it too didn't work — also too wet, and too chocolatey.

How can I find a decent recipe for the filling? Are there any names I should be searching for?

Comment: Hello hulkingtickets, as your question stands it'll most likely be closed as primarily opinion based. To make the question more objective, post the recipes that you have already tried and objective criteria in which you want to improve it. It would also help if you were able to describe the cream are trying to emulate in more detail.

Comment: Could the filling have been a mousse?  They're creamy, with air whipped in.

Comment: @Jay : or you could consider this to be more like the 'name that dessert' type questions, and we could try to figure out what it is based on the description.

Comment: If you google 'oblatne' you should find many recipes for the chocolate cream filling, assuming this is the dessert you are trying to make. Ukrainian waffle cake may also yield some results.

Comment: @Cindy probably a good answer? Seems to match the description.

Comment: I take it your grandma is no longer around to ask? Also, exactly where was your grandma from? (Granted, the cuisines are pretty similar for the three countries you list, but the languages are as different as it gets.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help.It's probably oblatne like @Cindy said.@Marti: my grandma have been in a few countries in Europe in all the mess that was WW2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we are talking about a variety of the Eastern European treat called ***Oblatne*** (or a variety of that name)? Which consists of five to eight layers of store-bought wafers (not "waffles" - in some languages it's the same term for both, I know), "glued together" by a fatty or caramelly cream, pressed for a few hours and cut into little diamonds? Like below:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://heneedsfood.com/2011/01/oblatne-croatian-wafer-cake/)</sup>

There are two main methods to create the cream, one based on condensed milk, dulce de leche or caramel, the other on butter, margarine or shortening. Often with an addition of nuts, chocolate and a dash of alcohol. Often, some raw eggs are included as well, so take the appropriate measures for these recipes.

The common trait is *low humidity* in the filling, because otherwise the wafers become soggy and - worst case - could even disintegrate.

Recipe requests are off-topic here, but a creative use of the terms *wafer*, *cake*, *country of origin or some neighboring country*, *oblatne* or *oblate* and your preferred filling ingredients in your favourite seach engine should set you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recipe for a cream I use in Dobos torta; it's thick and could work well in the nápolyi/ostya (waffle cake, oblatne):

4 eggs
200 g powdered sugar
235 g unsalted butter
240 g dark chocolate
17 g vanilla sugar (in the US, you can buy this in European specialty grocery stores)

To make the cream:

1. Crack the eggs open and put them in the top of a double broiler.
   Heat it up until it’s hot but not boiling. Pull it off the heat and
   beat it with a whisk until cool.
2. Beat the butter until very soft and creamy (you can use a food
   processor).
3. Mix the butter and the chocolate and melt in the microwave (3x half
   a minute at 200 watts, mix each time).
4. Mix the vanilla sugar and the melted chocolate, then mix in the
   whipped eggs.

Your chocolate cream is ready for spreading.